# Three.js - Disable 3d object translations along x, y and z axis

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to disable the movement of a 3D model along the x, y and z axis. I would like to allow the user to rotate and zoom, but I suspect that moving it can only cause issues. I have found something to disable rotation, but no similar thing for translation.

**Possible Usability Issues:**

1. The rotation point shifts when translating along the axis, this will cause the rotation behaviour to be all messed up.
2. They could move the object outside of their window. I could set boundries, but what is the real use of a 3D model viewer if the user is just going to loose the object on accident.

In short: I would perfer to disable the feature to prevent possible usability issues.

I hope someone can tell me how to achieve this.

Comment: Did you try `controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );  controls.enablePan = false;` ?

Comment: Ahh I had to call it on the controls, not on the camera. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable panning with `OrbitControls` like so:

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
controls.enablePan = false;
```

See the source code for other options.

three.js r.92

Comment: Thank you! Due to not being a english native speaker I have overlooked the '.enablePan'. Thanks for notifying me!